# How to add a string as part of a variable name representing an integer, java

Tags: java

I want to add a string to a variable name that represents an integer. For example:

```
String test = "v1f1";
set_view(R.drawable.test);
```

And then ideally it would look for R.drawable.v1f1, but it looks for R.drawable.test instead, which doesn't exist.

Anyone know how to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do this with an enum, as long as you limit yourself to values existing in the enum:
e.g.

```
public enum Values {
    A,B,C,D;
}

String test = "A";
set_view(Values.valueOf(test));
```

You could even do it with integers it you were willing to be *really* evil-

```
int test=1;
set_view(values.valueOf(new String( ((char)(test+(int)'A')));
```

Comment: Likely, yes. But I was really just responding to the possibility of doing something close to an eval of a variable name in java. Couldn't get closer than enum.valuOf without doing reflection, which would've been cheating ;)

Comment: The R.drawable.v1f1 represented an integer place in memory where a picture was stored. Just using a map now to associate the String with the relevant R.drawable. Works brilliantly, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You'd have to use reflection to do this - but it's not generally a good idea. Why do you want to do this? What values might you have, and could you change it to use a collection of some kind?

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any dynamic naming capability in Java. You can sometimes get around it by using keys into HashMaps, but I don't see a way to do that in your situation.